# CardLayout not completely hiding other cards?

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I am building a game, and to switch between the login screen and the game screen, I am using a `CardLayout`.

The code I am using to switch between the screens is

```
Global.gameScreen = new GameScreen(Global.connectionHandler.clientSocket);
cards.add(Global.gameScreen,"gameScreen");
((CardLayout)cards.getLayout()).show(cards,"gameScreen");
```

What happens, though is after I switch the screen, if I move my mouse over where the Swing controls in the login screen were, they appear and I can interact with them.

Is there a specific way I should switch cards?

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See also [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props).

Comment: Are you calling `repaint()` and `validate()`?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. You're telling me to call repaint and validate on cards, right?

Comment: Another thing, I found that this problem only occurs when run as an applet. It doesn't happen in a normal Java application.

Comment: I solved the problem. I just removed and readded the panel, and it worked.

Comment: If you understand why, post the result as an answer; if not, be wary of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply adding

```
getContentPane().remove(cards);
getContentPane().add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I don't know if this is the right way to solve it, but it worked for me.